# mapreduce reducer size is wrong

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a simple MapReduce program for counting the number of times each line appears in the input. My goal is to check that two directories contains the same data. Therefore in the reduce phase my goal is to check that each key appears exactly twice (one in every input directory)

This is my code -

```
public class ResultsValidator extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static class TuplesScanner extends Mapper<BytesWritable, NullWritable, BytesWritable, LongWritable> {

        private LongWritable one = new LongWritable(1);

        @Override
        public void map(BytesWritable row, NullWritable ignored, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            context.write(row, one);
        }
    }

    public static class TuplesCombiner extends Reducer<BytesWritable, LongWritable, BytesWritable, LongWritable> {

        @Override 
        public void reduce(BytesWritable row, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (LongWritable value : values) {
                sum += value.get();
            }
            context.write(row, new LongWritable(sum));
        }
    }

    public static class TuplesReducer extends Reducer<BytesWritable, LongWritable, BytesWritable, NullWritable> {

        @Override 
        public void reduce(BytesWritable row, Iterable<LongWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (LongWritable value : values) {
                sum += value.get();
            }
            if (sum != 2) {
                context.write(row, NullWritable.get());
            }
        }
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf());

        Path inputDir0 = new Path(args[0]);
        Path inputDir1 = new Path(args[1]);
        Path outputDir = new Path(args[2]);
        int reducersNum = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        if (outputDir.getFileSystem(getConf()).exists(outputDir)) {
          throw new IOException("Output directory " + outputDir + 
                                " already exists.");
        }
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputDir0);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputDir1);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputDir);
        job.setJobName("ResultsValidator");
        job.setJarByClass(ResultsValidator.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TuplesScanner.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(TuplesCombiner.class);
        job.setReducerClass(TuplesReducer.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(reducersNum);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(BytesWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(BytesWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(ResultsValidatorInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(ResultsValidatorOutputFormat.class);
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new ResultsValidator(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }
}
```

I can't find the reason why I get a wrong number in the iterable of the reduce phase. In the logs , I find that each reducer gets a number equals to the number of shuffle that were merged.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by "wrong"? What you described is the correct behaviour.

Comment: I use this code to compare two directories, each containing many files. My goal is to detect whether the directories are identical, but the identity depends on the LINES of the files. Each directory contain unique lines. No line appears more than once in each directory. Namely, I should check that all lines that are in the first directory are contained in the second, and vice versa. I map every line, and check in the reducer that each key appers twice. The program works for small inputs, but falis when my directories are more than 100MB each.